# How do I prevent the uploaded photo from being deleted when the page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an input for uploading the image in my project that I have implemented with reactjs.

So far, there is no problem, but after uploading the photo, when the user refreshes the page, the photo will be deleted.

How can I prevent the photo from being deleted when the page is refreshed?

**Edited:**

The file upload component gives me an object that I save as a blob in the state to render. And I also save the same object in the state to send it to the server

```js
<Stack sx={Styles.CameraAndGallaryBox}>
  <input
    accept="image/*"
    style={{ display: "none" }}
    id="raised-button-file"
    type="file"
    onChange={saveImageHandler}
  />
  <label htmlFor="raised-button-file">
    <Button variant="raised" component="span" sx={Styles.button}>
      <Gallary />
      <FormattedMessage id="gallary" />
    </Button>
  </label>
</Stack>
```

```js
const saveImageHandler = (e) => {
  history.push("/meta-search/image/visual-search");
  dispatch(setImageBlobUrl(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))); // for rendering
  dispatch(setImageFile(e.target.files[0])); // to send to the server
  dispatch(visualImageSearch({page:1})); // call api and send photo to server
};
```

Comment: You can persist the photo inside the local storage of the browser depending upon type of your photo. When use refreshes the page, check if you have any photo in your localstorage, if yes then retrieve that and set it into the state.

Comment: The photo is deleted from where?  It won't be deleted from the user's system, and it won't be deleted from the server unless you delete it.

Comment: Is the image getting saved in any database?

Comment: are you uploading to some server ? s3 ? then on refresh useffect make an ajax call to return the image

Comment: do you upload to the server or not? or is it just an app that doesn't include the api system logic?

Comment: @TimRoberts
Dear, I edited my question. If it is still unclear, tell me to explain more

Comment: @AnveegSinha No, I send to the server

Comment: Yes, I send it to server by api call . @TachibanaShin

Comment: Yes, I send it to server by api call . @ShoyebMemon

Comment: if so then there's no reason why it's deleted did you call the data back from the server when mounting the component?

Comment: The server belongs to another team and now I can't ask them to give me the possibility to request the photo from them.
I was looking for an easier way :)

As @ShubhamWaje said, can I save in localstorage?

Comment: Hi, the best way would be to store it in the server and fetch it but if you want to store it locally it would be better to use indexDB instead of localstorage